# how to know if the result of an ajax request is json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm doing an ajax request using $.get and as result I could get a simple string or JSON, how to know if the result is JSON (object) or not ?

**EDIT:**

can I return a string and somehow transform it into object/JSON ?

Comment: This is really more of a data contract issue than anything else. The data you get back from a $.get call should be reliable.

Comment: @Patrick dw not really, when I do result.substr() and the result is a json result, i get error that substr is not a function (so it's an object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `typeof` method to determine if it's an object or a String. If you want to convert a String to a JSON object, and if you trust the source you can use `eval`. Otherwise use a JSON parser, such as http://www.json.org/json_parse.js

Comment: typeof(result) == 'object' did it

Answer (score 5):

Its not 100% but server probably set responce header: `Content-Type: application/json`. So you can try to check it:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
    var spoiler = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
    spoiler == 'application/json' ? alert('JSON received') : alert('Not JSON received');
  }
});
```

Sure, it worked only if your server sets its headers in correct way.

One more way - is try to create a function and catch errors you may have.

```
try {
  x = ( new Function('return ' + received_data) )();
}
catch (e) { 
  console.log('Its not a JSON data... or its invalid.');
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most standards-compliant way to deal with content negotiation.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would expect to know what the data type is, but if for some reason you don't, how about checking the 'Content-Type' header.  In theory it should be 'application/json':

```
function responseHandler() {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
        if (http_request.status == 200) {
            if(http_request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == 'application/json') {
                // JSON
            }
            else {
                // Not JSON
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll have to check that the server is setting the Content-Type header correctly.  Also, not sure if this will work in IE- probably not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getJSON() instead

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

For the edit:

You can use

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        url: service,
        error:  function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            failureFunction(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        success:    function(data){
            successFunction(data);
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
```

With dataType Text, and parse for JSON from there.

jQuery.parseJSON( json ) - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: my request can return a simple html content or json

Answer (score 0):

You should know. Each url should only return one type of data.

Comment: +1 Because this true. An URL should not "randomly" return a data format.

Comment: Because, in this case for example, how do you tell the difference between a string that happens to contain JSON or a JSON object?

Comment: typeof(theString) is going to be string, 1 difference

Answer (score 0):

You know how the data is coming and you can do a null check to

Like

if it is a string constructed json , do a Eval of result

```
IF(EmployeeDetails.SalaryDetails.lenght)
{
   forloop()
}
```

Comment: you can even check in the firebug the result , the latest firebut in the netpanel has a json tab, if it is true json object it shows that structure